Oracle case on REGEXP_LIKE return false instead true
I have this query
select
    documentat2_.*
    ,case
            when (
                REGEXP_LIKE(documentat2_.VALUE,'^(\\*)$')
            ) then 1
            else 0
        END AS x
from
    DOCUMENT_ATTRIBUTE_BANK documentat1_
inner join
    DOCUMENT_ATTRIBUTE documentat2_
        on documentat1_.DOCUMENT_ATTRIBUTE_ID=documentat2_.DOCUMENT_ATTRIBUTE_ID
where
    exists  (
       select
            documenten0_.DOCUMENT_ID as document_id2_8_
            FROM 
             DOCUMENT documenten0_
        where
            documenten0_.APPLICATION_CODE='xxx' AND 
        documentat1_.DOCUMENT_ID=documenten0_.DOCUMENT_ID
        and documentat1_.DOCUMENT_VERSION=documenten0_.DOCUMENT_VERSION
    )
    and documentat1_.DOCUMENT_VERSION=16
    and documentat1_.BANK_ID='xxxx'
    and documentat2_.CHECKLIST_ID=7
    and documentat2_.NAME='NEW'
    AND documentat2_.VALUE='*'

The query selects records that match field VALUE=' * ' and it works ok, but REGEXP_LIKE return 0! My expectation is 1, not 0! It works with REGEXP_LIKE(documentat2_.VALUE,'(\\ *)') but not with
REGEXP_LIKE(documentat2_.VALUE,'^(\\ *)$'), why?
In other cases REGEXP_LIKE(documentat2_.VALUE, '^(NO)$|^(\\*)$') it works, because some records has VALUES with "NO" and others with "*". There are no spaces in fields i suppose, so i cant understand why it works so?
What's wrong, or i'm wrong?
I'm confused..
Thanks

Please post a [mre]. The join or where condition doesn't seem relevant to the regular expression test.

The regexp only matches when the value is exactly *, with no spaces before or after it. There's no reason to use a regexp, just use documentat2_.VALUE = '*'

@Barmar it's a test. The exact query receive as input the patter (from a web interface). "where documentat2_.VALUE = '*' " is only for select * values to check against a regular expressions give in the question..

The users enter regular expressions in the web interface?

Your question is unclear about what is going wrong in the query as you've written it. Please post sample data, the expected result, and the result you're getting instead.

You have a different regexp in the code block than the text of the question. The code has ^(\\*)$, the question has (\\ *) and ^(\\ *)$. Which is the actual regexp you're using?

^(\\*)$ matches:

The start of the string ^
The start of a capturing group (
Zero-or-more \ backslash characters \\*
The end of a capturing group )
The end of the string $.

It doesn't match a * character.
If you want to match a * then use a single backslash to escape the * character:
select documentat2_.*
     , case
       when (REGEXP_LIKE(documentat2_.VALUE,'^\*$'))
       then 1
       else 0
       END AS x
from   -- ...
       DOCUMENT_ATTRIBUTE documentat2_
where  -- ...
       documentat2_.VALUE='*'

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE DOCUMENT_ATTRIBUTE (value) AS
SELECT '*' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '  *  ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



VALUE
X




*
1



fiddle

Isn't \\  a literal backslash to the string parser, which then becomes an escaping backslash to the regexp engine? So it's escaping the * character.

@Barmar No, \\ is escaping the second backslash.

But doesn't it escape it to the string literal parser?

@Barmar No, a backslash has no special meaning in a string literal. If you want to escape a single quote in a literal then use two single quotes but everything else is as-written.

Thanks, I was assuming it's similar to MySQL string literals.

Thank you very much, the double escape is only in java, when i try to copy query in SQL Client i miss to delete one backslash! Sorry i havent thinking about it..
